# Screen.width/ $(window).width() Media Queires

Tags: html, css, media-queries

So it seems that in mobile devices media queries uses `screen.width` which does not change at all. But on my desktop when I change the window size , `screen.width` stays the same, `$(window).width()` changes, and the proper style sheet get applied. So it seems that in desktop browser media queries uses `$(window).width()` This baffles me.

Code example my media queries

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1050px), only screen and (max-device-width: 1050px){
 --other stuff
 background-color: lightgray;

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px), only screen and (max-device-width: 800px){
   -- other stuff
   background-color: orchid;
```

On my desktop `screen.width` is 1920 and `$(window).width()` is 1027 and the first style sheet get applied, when I made the window smaller and `screen.width` is 1920 and `$(window).width()` is 738 the second style also get applied overriding the first style sheet background color. So the value of `$(window).width()` determines the style sheet

On safari mobile in my ipad simulator in portrait mode `screen.width` is 768 and `$(window).width()` is 768 and as expected both style sheet is applied. But when I change to landscape mode `screen.width` is 768 and `$(window).width()` is 1024, both style sheet are still being applied since the second style sheet is overriding the background color of the first one when it shouldn't.

At the top of my index.html I do have this meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

I don;t know if this would affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

According to this website http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml Iphones and ipads give the device width as if you are holding the device in portrait mode. You could use the "orientation : landscape" css to achieve different styles for portrait and landscape.

This website http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/ lists a lot of css media queries to target specific apple devices.

Hope this helps